# linksys ae2500 n600 dual-band wireless-n usb adapter for Ubuntu 14 - 64 bit doesn't work at all

Tags: 14.04, wireless, drivers, 64-bit, ndiswrapper

I have Ubuntu 14.04 lts 64 bit and have installed ndiswrapper and ndisgtk and when I load the *.inf file from xp driver It says "Invalid Driver" that is crossed out with a red X. Now I've read around and I'm only hearing about 32 bit versions of linux, but there must be a way to do it on a 64 bit platform. I'm just putting this out there if anybody has an answer or has solved this issue. Anyway cheers and keep the terminal open always.

Comment: Is your device, per `lsusb` 13b1:003a? What does this tell us? `dmesg | grep ndis`? Please edit your question to add the result. Are you using bcmwlhigh5.inf?

Answer (score -1):

the drivers that provides from linksys doesn't work with ndiswrapper. But I got a special driver from the chipset bcmwlhigh5 from the buried wikidevi. It have both 32bit & 64bit. But beware, wireless networks protected by password doesn't connect (unless you're lucky). Anyway it can connect to unprotected wifi networks.

[bcmwlhigh5.inf](https://mega.nz/#!G9JXzR6b!wYov5BYvVAcuIJyWYWrjJec6LchIFTK6uJZiw_-kYrQ)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to use this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)